# PHP Laravel get data by week from db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello i have this code

```
  // Get all the days date of past month for performance report
    $start_date = date("Y-m", strtotime("previous month")) ."-01";
    $start_time = strtotime($start_date);

    $end_time_1 = strtotime("+1 week", $start_time);

    for($i=$start_time; $i<$end_time_1; $i+=86400)
    {
    $list1[] = date('D, d F Y', $i);
    }

    $end_time_2 = strtotime("+1 week", $end_time_1);

    for($i=$end_time_1; $i<$end_time_2; $i+=86400)
    {
    $list2[] = date('D, d F Y', $i);
    }

    $end_time_3 = strtotime("+1 week", $end_time_2);

    for($i=$end_time_2; $i<$end_time_3; $i+=86400)
    {
    $list3[] = date('D, d F Y', $i);
    }

    $end_time_4 = strtotime("+1 week", $end_time_3);

    for($i=$end_time_3; $i<$end_time_4; $i+=86400)
    {
    $list4[] = date('D, d F Y', $i);
    }

    $performance_week_1 = \DB::table('accounts')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date, $end_time_1]) // get week 1
    ->get();
    $performance_week_2 = \DB::table('accounts')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$end_time_1, $end_time_2]) // get week 2
    ->get();
    $performance_week_3 = \DB::table('accounts')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$end_time_2, $end_time_3]) // get week 3
    ->get();
    $performance_week_4 = \DB::table('accounts')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$end_time_3, $end_time_4]) // get week 4
    ->get();
```

What it does is it gets all the date of the days of the past month 
[image: Report]

The problem is `end_time_1` return

> 1549584000

i want it to return what `$start_time` returns but + 1 week from this month

> 2019-02-08

The idea is to get somedata from db by every week from the last month and post it to table
  Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [ADDDATE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_adddate.asp) mysql function for that, for example:

```
SELECT ADDDATE("2019-02-08", INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

That will add 7 days to the date, this can also be the date of column

PS. you should use laravel's DB:raw() function for this

Answer (score 0):

CHange one line to get required format of date:

```
$end_time_1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 week", $start_time));
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer i tried and i got A non well formed numeric value encountered

Answer (score 0):

Hello Thanks very much for the help i did that and it worked

i changed `->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date, $end_time_1])`
to `->whereBetween('created_at', [date('Y-m-d',$end_time_1), date('Y-m-d',$end_time_2)])`
   Now it works just fine thank you very much

Comment: Someone tell me if there is a better way to do it